# How to get Image to move back down when done

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Currently I have a TCard (TGraphicControl) that I move the x up in small steps.  But I cant figure out how to move it back down.

I start it with

```
           TCardMover.Slide(card,point(card.Left,card.Top -10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation);
```

inside this
{this will give the attack amimation}

```
procedure TGameData.AnimateAttack(slot: Integer;card: TCard);  //add value as integer ,
var
i : integer;
begin
i:=0;
   if slot = 1 then
        begin
           //TCardMover.Slide(card,point(card.Left,card.Top -10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation,nil);
           TCardMover.Slide(Card,point(Card.Left,Card.Top -10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation,TerminateCall);
        end;
   if slot = 2 then
        begin
          TCardMover.Slide(card,point(card.Left,card.Top -10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation,TerminateCall);  // DMc Just to test card movement
        end;
   if slot = 3  then
        begin
          TCardMover.Slide(card,point(card.Left,card.Top -10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation,TerminateCall);  // DMc Just to test card movement
        end;
end;
```

and then i call it like

```
procedure TGameData.attack;
begin
    animateAttack(1,fgame.Slot1);
end;
```

if i run tCardMover.slide right after itself like this, in the animateattack.

```
   TCardMover.Slide(card,point(card.Left,card.Top -10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation);
   TCardMover.Slide(card,point(card.Left,card.Top +10),CARD_SLIDE_TIME,Animation);
```

it try's to do both, i assume due to the moving is a separate thread?  how can i fix this so i can move out -10  then move +10 once the card is finished moving -10?

and here is TCardMover.

```
{ TCardMover }

function TCardMover.Arrived: boolean;
begin
  Result := (FPosNow.X = FPosDest.X) and (FPosNow.Y = FPosDest.Y);
end;

procedure TCardMover.CalculateNextStop;
var
  Elapsed : integer;
begin
  while FTickNext < GetTickCount do                 // When is next re-draw due?
    FTicknext := FTickNext + CARD_MOVE_INTERVAL;


  if FTickNext >= FTickEnd then   // Are we there yet Dad?
  begin                           // If the journey has taken long enough, move
    FTickNext := FTickEnd;        // to our destination without further delay,
    FPosNow   := FPosDest;        // then bail.
  end
  else
  begin
    // If we get here we are still en route so calculate where to re-draw.
    Elapsed := GetTickCount - FTickStart;                // How much time will journey have taken at next re-draw?
    FPosNow.X := FPosStart.X + round((Elapsed/FTickJourney)*FJourney.X);  // Where will card be at next re-draw?
    FPosNow.Y := FPosStart.Y + round((Elapsed/FTickJourney)*FJourney.Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TCardMover.Execute;
begin
  while not terminated and not Arrived do
  begin
    CalculateNextStop;
    WaitTillDue;
    Synchronize(NotifyHost);
  end;
end;

class procedure TCardMover.Slide(aCard: TCard; aDestination: TPoint; aJourneyTime: cardinal; DrawProc : TNotifyEvent);
begin
  with TCardMover.Create(START_IMMEDIATELY) do
  begin
    FTickStart      := GetTickCount;
    FTickNext       := FTickStart;
    FTickEnd        := FTickStart + aJourneyTime;
    FPosStart       := Point(aCard.Left,aCard.Top);
    FCard           := aCard;
    FPosDest        := aDestination;
    FTickJourney    := aJourneyTime;
    FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;
    FOnMove         := DrawProc;
    FJourney.X      := FPosDest.X - FPosStart.X;
    FJourney.Y      := FPosDest.Y - FPosStart.Y;
  end;
end;

procedure TCardMover.NotifyHost;
begin
  if assigned(FOnMove) then
    FOnMove(Self);
end;

procedure TCardMover.WaitTillDue;
var
  TicksNow : cardinal;
begin
  TicksNow := GetTickCount;
  if TicksNow < FTickNext then
    SleepEx(FTickNext-TicksNow,DO_NOT_QUIT_EARLY);
end;
```

Comment: Your Thread has only a waiting part and a sychronized moving part. You can handle this with a simple TTimer on your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would start with an object as an Animator that triggers several Animations

```
type
  IAnimation = interface
   {GUID}
   function IsFinished : Boolean;
   procedure Step;
 end;

 TAnimator = class
 private
   FAnimations : TList<IAnimation>;
   FTimer : TTimer;
   procedure TimerEvent( Sender : TObject );
 public
   constructor Create;
   destructor Destroy; override;
   procedure Add( AAnimation : IAnimation );
 end;

constructor TAnimator.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FAnimations := TList<IAnimation>.Create;

  FTimer := TTimer.Create( nil );
  FTimer.Interval := 25; // whatever you like
  FTimer.OnTimer := TimerEvent;
  FTimer.Enabled := True;
end;

destructor Destroy;
begin
  FTimer.Free;
  FAnimations.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TAnimator.Add( AAnimation : IAnimation );
begin
  FAnimations.Add( AAnimation );
end;

procedure TAnimator.TimerEvent( Sender : TObject );
var
  LIdx : Integer;
  LAnimation : IAnimation;
begin
  LIdx := 0;
  while LIdx < FAnimations.Count do
  begin
    LAnimation := FAnimations[LIdx];
    LAnimation.Step;
    if LAnimation.IsFinished then
      FAnimations.Remove( LAnimation )
    else
      Inc( LIdx );
  end;
end;
```

Thats all you need to have animations of all kind you like ...

e.g. Let's build an Animation-Sequence

```
type
  TAnimationSequence = class( TInterfacedObject, IAnimation )
  private
    FAnimations : TQueue<IAnimation>;
    function IsFinished : Boolean;
    procedure Step;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Add( AAnimation : IAnimation );
  end;

constructor TAnimationSequence.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FAnimations := TQueue<IAnimation>.Create;
end;

destructor TAnimationSequence.Destroy;
begin
  FAnimations.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TAnimationSequence.IsFinished : Boolean;
begin
  Result := FQueue.Count = 0;
end;

procedure Step;
var
  LAnimation : IAnimation;
begin
  LAnimation := FAnimations.Peek;
  LAnimation.Step;
  if LAnimation.IsFinished then
    LAnimation := FAnimations.Dequeue;
end;
```

Now you should be able to build your own animations and combine them also to a sequence

```
var
  LSequence : TAnimationSequence;
begin
  LSequence := TAnimationSequence.Create;

  LSequence.Add( TControlMoveUpAnimation.Create( MyCard, 10 ) );
  LSequence.Add( TControlMoveDownAnimation.Create( MyCard, 10 ) );
  LSequence.Add( TControlMoveUpAnimation.Create( MyCard, 8 ) );
  LSequence.Add( TControlMoveDownAnimation.Create( MyCard, 8 ) );
  LSequence.Add( TControlMoveUpAnimation.Create( MyCard, 4 ) );
  LSequence.Add( TControlMoveDownAnimation.Create( MyCard, 4 ) );

  MyAnimator.Add( LSequence );
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to add an aditional Parameter to your class method and provide an OnTerminate Event. So the second thread will be called after the first terminated:

```
class procedure TCardMover.Slide(aCard: TShape; aDestination: TPoint; 
           aJourneyTime:cardinal ; DrawProc : TNotifyEvent; CallOnTerminate: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  with TCardMover.Create(false) do
  begin
    FTickStart      := GetTickCount;
    // .....
    OnTerminate := CallOnTerminate;
  end;
end;


procedure TAForm.TerminateCall(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TCardMover.Slide(Card ,point(Card.Left,Card.Top +100),50,Animation,nil);
end;

// Call the method and provide a procedure which will be called if the thread terminates
begin
 TCardMover.Slide(Card,point(Card.Left,Card.Top -100),50,Animation,TerminateCall);
end;
```

An other way could be to change your TCardMover class to handle a list of animations.

Comment: ok i tried this but a few issues.. First i have updated how i attack..  I call attack giving a slot and TCard.  Then i run the AnimateAttack using those values.  Thus not sure how to setup the TerminateCall procedure.

Comment: mostly cause i am not sure how to send the data "slot" and "Card" back to this procedure with out getting errors.

Comment: Since you are using TNotifyEvents you are able to access TCardMover(Sender) within the events. You are able to provide any information you will need with your class procedure slide to the thread. It's the same as you access to PosNow in your DrawProc.

Comment: weird , in the terminatecall i get errors on card and card.left/right  one differentce is i have TGamedata.Terminatecall where as with posNow and Drawproc i use TCardmover.posnow. ect..  ill try adding it to TCardMover